# Permission denied (publickey). scp: Connection closed

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, scp

I'm having a remote server running SSH,

I use the scp from my local computer like this:

```
scp filename.txt username@IP:/data/production
```

it asks for the password, I supplied it,  and then I get

```
username@IP: Permission denied (publickey).
scp: Connection closed
```

Comment: Login in to the remote machine and check if you can do the follow: `touch /data/production/filename.txt`

Comment: Try running scp (or plain ssh) with the "-v" flag to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the output. You say you're entering a password, but the error message refers to public keys. Do you mean you're entering a public key passphrase?